# Почему WebView не слушается веса?

Tags: android-view, android

В разметке должны отображаться две (SVG) картинки и WebView. Для оптимального отображения каждый из них помещён в свой LinearLayout. Для каждой из картинок задан вес в 40%, для WebView - оставшиеся 20% (всего 100%).

Но при портретной ориентации (визуально) картинки занимают процентов 90, и  WebView - 10 (полоской где-то внизу экрана). А при горизонтальной ориентации возникает картина с точностью до -наоборот, на 90 процентов раздвигается WebView и 10 оставляет на две картинки.

Загадочно! Как, вообще, можно жёстко привязать элементы к месту в разметке?

Может что-то посоветуете?

Я "грешу" на WebView потому, что если в разметке оставить две картинки, то они делят строго экран поровну и в любой ориентации и на любом разрешении ведут себя как паиньки.

Код портретной разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fon"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutImageOne"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/about_image" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutImageTwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/about_image" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Код горизонтальной разметки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fon"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutImageOne"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/about_image" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.40"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/aboutImageTwo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/about_image" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @fundator, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Прошу прощения за невежество - на какую галку (у меня ничего такого не видно).

Comment: под кнопкой "понизить уровень ответа"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у элементов, у которых выставлен вес, нужно выставлять размерность, за которую отвечает вес в 0dp. Иначе вес не окажет эффекта.

Comment: Ура заработало!!!
Огромное СПАСИБО!!!
Дай Бог здоровья и денег!